# Namespace of same project not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, compiler-errors, projects-and-solutions

In VS2010 running with .Net 4.0, I have a solution which has a website project. This website project has a folder called Lobby under which there is a class called Catalog. So the address of this class is now `Lobby.Catalog`

In the same website I have a folder called Users which has an aspx file called `Manage.aspx` and `Manage.aspx.cs`

Now in the attempt to migrate from website project to web application project, I have created a new web application project in the same solution and added both the files sans the folders to it. There is no reference between the Website project and the Web Application Project. Both files `Manage.aspx.cs` and `Catalog.cs` are in the same project. `Lobby.Catalog` is my class which has just a few string properties. However, when in the `Manage.aspx.cs` class when I try to add a using statement `using Lobby`, I get an error: `error CS0246: Type or namespace could not be found`

How can this be? It is in the same project. I have cleaned solution, restarted visual studio, rebuilt the project and still no benefit.

Comment: Can you screenshot the structure?

Comment: Do you have a "namespace Lobby" declaration at the top of Catalog.cs?

Comment: Check the `namespace` declaration in your `Catalog.cs` class matches what your `Manage.aspx.cs` class expects

Comment: I have simplified the solution for the problem statement. Cant use actual solution screenshots as I might be breaking some company policy.

Comment: I had this problem yesterday. Check that the target framework for each project is the same.

Comment: @MobyDisk: yes I do have it at the top of Catalog.cs as namespace Lobby { public class Catalog....

Comment: dav_i: both these files are in the same project now. and the place I copied them from is in another website project of the same solution. but there is no reference between this website project and the current web application project.

Comment: @robh: I copied the same namespace name from the catalog class and pasted it in the aspx file. but in the aspx file I still get the red squiggly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that the BuildAction for both the file must be "Compile" and not any other typically its set to "Content"
2. Check the namespaces of both the files, it should be accessible.